# How to unpack a list in stages (specman)

Tags: specman

I have a list of bit, which I would like to unpack to stages,
Stage #1 unpack it to struct A, and depending on the value i receive in A.next field i would like to unpack the "REST" to another struck, which can be B, C or D.

My problem is how to inform the next unpack from where to start unpacking.
Code:

```
unpack(packing.low, l, A);
if (A.next==B) {unpack(packing.low, l, B, LAST_UNPACK_SIZE)};
if (A.next==C) {unpack(packing.low, l, C, LAST_UNPACK_SIZE)};
if (A.next==D) {unpack(packing.low, l, D, LAST_UNPACK_SIZE)};
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, for the purpose of customizing unpacking, it's suggested to extend the method do_unpack() of the struct. From outside the packing will remain simple, and inside you can encapsulate the logic. But not sure it matches your flow, because from A variable you probably can't access B,C,D variables.

For this specific case, you might try some trick, like passing a buffer list of bit to the first stage and then unpacking the rest from the buffer:

```
unpack(packing.low, l, A, buffer);
case A.next {
    B: { unpack(packing.low, buffer, B) };
    C: { unpack(packing.low, buffer, C) };
    D: { unpack(packing.low, buffer, D) };
    default: { error(...) };
};
```